# Display posts with pagination

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I have a blog page in my wordpress site `http://jarm.shahumyanmedia.com/blog/`. 
Here the blogs are posts, and I need to display 5 posts for each page, but I can't display pagination link.

This is how I am getting posts:

```
$posts = get_posts( array(
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'category' => 5)
);
```

And this is how I am trying to get pagination links:

```
<?php wp_link_pages(); ?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_link_pages

But I don't see any output.

Comment: Your second code paste is missing. And did you check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864578/paginate-posts-in-wordpress-theme?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Install and active this plugin and add this code..

http://www.devdevote.com/cms/wordpress-plugins/wp-paging

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
query_posts('paged='.$paged.'&posts_per_page=5&orderby=date&cat=5&order=DESC');
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
  ....

endwhile;
wp_paging();
```